# Do I need a paid plan for using recaptcha on firebase function?

Tags: firebase, recaptcha

I created a firebase function for making my website's recaptcha validation, but I'm getting the error that people get when they have the Spark (free) plan and try to send a request to an external api.

This is my error: [Firebase functions ENOTFOUND on all http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856789/firebase-functions-enotfound-on-all-http-requests/42857110#42857110)

And this is an error when someone else requested an external API: [Firebase functions - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sandbox.paypal.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774807/firebase-functions-getaddrinfo-enotfound-api-sandbox-paypal-com?rq=1)

From Firebase's [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) page:

> The Spark plan only allows outbound network requests to Google owned services

**Google owned services** they say, so this shouldn't be a problem when requesting a recaptcha validation, right?

Comment: I got the same problem. After I upgraded the plan, it works.

Answer (score 2):

It it no longer necessary to be on the paid plan to call the reCAPTCHA server API as it was recently whitelisted (as long as you're accessing it via recaptcha.google.com).  You can read more about that [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/guard-your-web-content-from-abuse-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

Something in your code is reaching out to `api.sandbox.paypal.com`, which is not a Google-owned service. So you will indeed need to be on a paid plan for that.

Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it has hard to say *what* precisely calls Paypal.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but paypal is just an example of someone else reporting the same error. My code is the one in the first link, and it's the entire code of the function.