# Error on Google Functions (free) trying to access reCaptcha verify

Tags: express, google-cloud-functions, recaptcha

I'm new to Google Cloud Functions and reCAPTCHA. I've built my site using AngularJS and Express.js for the back-end. 
I've used express-recaptcha v5.0.1 for the Express.js.

I've tested the reCAPTCHA (both front-end and back-end) and it works fine when I run locally.

But when I deploy the back-end, I'm getting the following error from Google Cloud Functions:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN www.google.com:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
```

Is reCAPTCHA verify method blocked by the free plan of Google Cloud Functions?

This S/O seems to indicate that should be fine: [Do I need a paid plan for using recaptcha on firebase function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857827/do-i-need-a-paid-plan-for-using-recaptcha-on-firebase-function)

How can I debug this further?

Comment: My answer over there is suggesting that a specific hostname is required to make this work.  What you're showing is that some bit of code is trying to access www.google.com, instead of the approved recaptcha.google.com

Comment: According to this page: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api_request the URL is `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` with a POST.

Comment: If things don't work the way you expect, please file an issue with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After raising a support case with Firebase team, it turned out that the only way to get the API to work is to use this URL `https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` as Doug mentioned in the comment.

So I will have to write my own module/middleware to do the verification to get it to work on the "free" Firebase tier.

Comment: So Ben, any progress on your own middleware? Can download? Same problem here, LOL

Comment: @AntonioOoi, Yes, it's working as expected with the new URL. No need to pay.